# Powershell - check folder for new files since the last time the script was ran

Tags: c#, powershell

I have next to no experience with scripts, but I managed to make a script using FileSystemWatcher to work (it generates a pop up when there is a file added to the watched folder).

The script isn't being ran all time and files can be added folder can be made during this time. I would like to have the script also check if there has been new files added since the last time the script was ran.

I believe the approach would be to create a log.txt file that saves the time of the most recent file created. Then the script compares if there is a newer file than the one in the log when initially executed (if there is a newer file, it saves this to the log). The part I am stuck on is how to make and use the log file in this way.

Comment: You can create a task schedule to have the script run at different times throughout the day to check. Appending information to a log based off certain circumstances can be easy, unless there's other stuff involved. You can use `Out-File` or cmdlets as such that fit your needs. If you can come up with some script to try and I what you want, with a desired result, we can assist with that.

Comment: @eschre taka a look hier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177875/file-watcher-with-powershell-not-triggering-always  or https://mcpmag.com/articles/2019/05/01/monitor-windows-folder-for-new-files.aspx